# Manual proxy configuration to 127.0.0.1 in firefox refuse internet connection

Tags: firefox, proxy, localhost, config, helper

I change my firefox browser proxy to 127.0.0.1 by manual configuration. After that, i try to browser some webpages but the error proxy server refuse connections happens. I try so many ways but it did not work. How can i fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REiv3.png)